# KeyEvent not being sent to the expected Component after a requestFocusInWindow

Tags: java, swing, focus, awt, awtrobot

I use a java.util.Robot to send key events to some components of my Swing App. I've got the following issue: to send an event to an unfocused component, I call requestFocusInWindow (from the AWT thread to have the type-ahead garanty as indicated in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/doc-files/FocusSpec.html), then I wait for the FOCUS_GAINED event to be received by the component. Then I post my key events using the Robot. But they get delivered to the wrong component...
If I wait at least 200 millis, it works ...

Any idea ?

(Using Java 1.6.0_21)

Comment: In a nutshell, your question is basically, "why isn't my code working as expected?", but without our seeing your code, it's likely anyone's guess. Your best chance of getting a decent answer is if you could post compilable runnable code that is as short as humanly possible yet is able to demonstrate your problem, an [sscce](http://sscce.org). Please check the link for the details since this type of construct can help you and us immensely if done well.

Comment: @user1715107 sorry no ideas :-)

Comment: Thanks, I guess I was hoping there could be a well known trick in which I fell, but it seems there is no, and I agree that at this point there is not much you can do without a demonstrative sample. I'll provide one if I find the time.